# Prism Library: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am using the Prims Library with WPF (on .net 4.8) for some time now and it´s a great framework. Since I have installed my software, on some computers of a new customer the app crashes quiet often.

The strange thing is that the app does not even manage to create a minidump (what it does on an unhandled exception). I can only see in the eventlog that there was a problem.

The message there looks like this - the constant pattern is that it always crashes in the ctr().

The local administrator has already checked and reinstalled .net 4.8. The binaries of the app are stored on an ofice network share (this also the case at most other customer installations).

Please let me know if there is a way to trace down the root cause.

```
Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319
Beschreibung: Der Prozess wurde aufgrund einer unbehandelten Ausnahme beendet.
Ausnahmeinformationen: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
   bei Reports.R41..ctor()

Ausnahmeinformationen: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
   bei Unity.Processors.ConstructorProcessor+<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<GetResolverDelegate>b__0(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   bei Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2+<>c__DisplayClass8_0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<GetResolver>b__0(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   bei Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2+<>c__DisplayClass8_0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<GetResolver>b__0(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   bei Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2+<>c__DisplayClass8_0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<GetResolver>b__0(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   bei Unity.Strategies.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   bei Unity.UnityContainer+<>c.<.ctor>b__73_1(Unity.Builder.BuilderContext ByRef)
   bei Unity.UnityContainer.Unity.IUnityContainer.Resolve(System.Type, System.String, Unity.Resolution.ResolverOverride[])
   bei Prism.Unity.UnityContainerExtension.Resolve(System.Type, System.String, System.ValueTuple`2<System.Type,System.Object>[])
   bei Prism.Ioc.IContainerProviderExtensions.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Prism.Ioc.IContainerProvider, System.String)
   bei Bauradar.Common.ViewModelBase.PrintCurrentReport(Bauradar.Support.ReportDefinition)
   bei MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(System.Windows.Input.ICommandSource, Boolean)
   bei System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(System.Object)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   bei MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   bei MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   bei MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   bei MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   bei System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   bei System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   bei Bauradar.Shell.App.Main()
```

Comment: It looks like you are calling through C++/CLI into some unmanaged code.  Probably the thing that has "bei Reports.R41." in its name?  Maybe a constructor?  If the umanaged code is throwing a C++ exception and the C++/CLI layer is not catching it, it gets turned into an SEHException.

Is that your code?  Do you have access to it?  Or is it a 3rd party thing?

Comment: Report.R41 is a class in my own code. The exception happens always in the constructor of my classes - but of very different kind: viewmodels as well as reports. The common aspect is the use of Unity as DI. I am not using unmanged code in my code.

Comment: Is there a chance that a virusscanner is a part of the problem?

Comment: Well InteropServices implies unmanaged code somewhere I think.  Have you tried setting the debugger to break on SEHException and see where it takes you?

Comment: The bad thing is that I cannot reproduce the exception, it happens only on the customer site and can also not be reproduced on the spot. It happens very likely once day. My next step is to delivery a full debug build including all available external pdbs. I understand that the exception indicates unmanaged code but the creator does not contains such code. There might be unmanaged code in 3rd party libs.

Comment: It is possible you have a missing DLL.  Ask your customer to make the problem happen.  Then immediately go to the start menu, type "Event" and when they see "Event Viewer" run that app.  Under Event Viewer, go to Windows Logs >> Application and look for any recent "Error" events (there will be a red exclamation point) that have a "source" that is your application.   If the problem is a missing DLL, there is a good chance the event will have it.

Comment: Barring that -- does your app have any C++/CLI assemblies in it?  I once had a similar problem that I could not solve without seeing what a 3rd party DLL was writing to std::cerr.  So I wrote a C++/CLI assembly with a managed object that wrapped an unmanaged object that intercepted std::cerr output and dumped it up to my managed logger.  Overkill maybe but it works.